# SQL column merge

Tags: mysql, sql, merge

```
Address1,
Address2,
TownCity,
Region,
Postcode,
Country,
```

Hi guys and gals,

I got a SQL problem.if you could help me with it that'd be awesome.

The table(softc) on top has couple of columns that id like to merge into a single column called "contactinfo"

Columns that needed to be merged:

```
Address1,
Address2,
TownCity,
Region,
Postcode,
Country,
```

I've tried UNION but it filters out rows with NULL values.I have 618 records.when i do a UNION it comes up with 750.(some records might contain all NULLs.but they are necessary to map the single into another table)

appreciate your help.thanks

---

I'm Working with mySQL

Comment: Which RDBMS do you use? SQL Server? MySQL? Oracle? DB2? Please make your tags more specific.

Comment: sorry i should've mentioned it.i'm working with mySQL.thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
select IFNull(Address1,'') + IFNull(Address2,'') + IFNull(TownCity,'') + IFNull(Region,'') + IFNull(Postcode,'') + IFNull(Country,'') as ContactInfo from Softc
```

That should be what you want...

Comment: This will return null if any of the field value is null. null + 'abc' =null. Try IsNull() function

Comment: Hi Martin thanks for your reply,but the query is returning all NULLs, i'm a SQL novice as you can probably tell,how do i include IsNull() to the query.and thanks miller for your input as well

Comment: I know you're grateful (from your feedback). It would be nice though if you could give an upvote to the other posters (won't ask for one myself...). You should also mark one answer as your accepted answer - you probably didn't realise this as you are new to the site...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 select  ISNULL(Address1,'') + ISNULL(' '+Address2,'') + ISNULL(', '+TownCity,'') 
 + ISNULL(', '+Region,'') + ISNULL(', '+Postcode,'') + ISNULL(', '+Country,'') as ContactInfo from Softc
```

Comment: Hi Miller thanks for the reply.I've tried IFNULL instead of ISNULL because i'm working with mySQl ...but it didn't workout.i got bunch of numbers instead of merged columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can combine combine / merge cells with Concat command

Example :

CONCAT([Firstname],',',[lastname]) as Fullname.

expression = concat[fieldname/seperator], [fieldname/seperator], ............... etc

Comment: Thanks Marcel, I've tried that but it seems it only return the records with all fields thats been filled.if there is a null value it wouldn't return it.
******************************************************
 select  CONCAT((Address1), Address2, TownCity, Postcode, Country)  as ContactInfo from softc
*****************************************************

Comment: By Adding ,<code> ISNULL(field,'defaultValue') </code> you can bypass empty values. Maybe a string.Format helps http://stringformat-in-sql.blogspot.nl/

Comment: thanks marcel, ive used ,

SELECT AppContactID AS id, CompanyName AS title, LTRIM( CONCAT( Address1,  ', ', Address2,  ', ',  `TownCity` ,  ', ', Postcode ) ) AS contactinfo, Phone1 AS contact, Phone2 AS contact2, email, WWW AS urls
FROM softc

All good now NULL are reporting back.so good times.thanks

Comment: if you're using mySql use Cohcat_Ws

Answer (score 0):

Part of database normalization is to break data into it's most discrete components.  You have that now.  Don't bollocks it up.

A good long term solution to your problem is to update all your null values to empty strings.  Then alter those columns so that they don't allow nulls and have a default value of empty strings.  This will allow your concatonation queries to run faster because you won't have to check for null values.

Also, if the requirement to return a contact info string is frequent, you can write a database function that returns it.

Comment: Thanks for your input Dan, this Db i'm working is not my design, i'm tryna migrate it to mySQL db from a old Access MDB